# run a function every x seconds in c++

Tags: c++, timer

I'm trying to build a feed reader in C++, so I need the program to check for new feeds intermittently. However, the user needs still to be able to interact with the program, so the suggestion that I seem to keep finding, to have the system wait, doesn't work for me. Can anyone suggest a better solution, say a timer that runs in the background or something?

Thanks,
Charles

Comment: A background timer alone would not cut it; it's entirely possible that while trying to read a feed your program would timeout on some network call for any reason not in your power to control, and this means that your program would freeze in this case too. To properly solve both issues, you will need to enter the magical world of multithreading...

Comment: are you using some sort of gui toolkit, or is this a simple commandline program?  if you are using a gui toolkit there is most likely an event loop you can attach a timer too for callbacks.

Comment: The correct method depends on operating systems and user interface toolkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a thread that sleeps for the specific time period.  This is OS independent.  Or, if you are programming in windows, you can set a timer to send a timeout event periodically.  The use of timers depends on your deployment platform.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that. I know it's quite subjective, but does it seem a little messy to simply have a thread pause, or is this just the way it's done?

Comment: Thread pauses are in fact really good - the operating system can say to itself "Okay, he won't be using that for the next x seconds; I can schedule some other task in the meantime". The alternative would be to have some loop which is running constantly and is constantly checking "is the time up yet?" In that case, the Operating System will continue to allocate time to the "paused" thread; which is thus more inefficient.

Comment: Be aware if you just have fixed pauses of 1 second, and the work takes half a second to complete, you end up running every 1.5 seconds.  You might want to take in to account the time the work took to do.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use threads. Have one thread in the background doing the timer, and one in the foreground interacting with the user. Then have some shared memory area between the threads that the background thread can modify by calling your particular function; and that the foreground one can view. Perhaps look into the boost thread library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use SIGALRM to get interupted every n seconds. This does not need a separate thread. You main thread will enter a signal handler.

```
void sigtime(int signo)
{
    signal(SIGALRM, sigtime);
}
....
signal(SIGALRM, sigtime);
itimerval itm;
itm.it_interval.tv_sec=0;
itm.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
itm.it_interval.tv_usec = 200000;
itm.it_value.tv_usec = 200000;
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL,&itm,0);
```

this of course assume you are on something unix-like

Comment: +1 and http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getitimer.html see also alarm http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/alarm.html which forgoes the structure for simple integral seconds

Answer (score 1):

Make the UI and feed reader separate threads. If the user does something that requires an immediate feed update, interrupt the feed thread.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to make a program which execute a function every x minutes or hours and i found many examples but for to make it, it  was necessary to include and download a library , and for me it was not comfortable and i made my own, not very logic)) but it works , you can see it below

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <time.h>
 using namespace std;

 struct tm *addtime(struct tm *tm2)
 {
      time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
     struct tm * tm1  = localtime( & t );
     cout << " Time begin : " << tm1->tm_hour << " : " << tm1->tm_min <<endl;
     struct tm * aux = (struct tm*)malloc(sizeof (struct tm));

     aux->tm_sec = tm1->tm_sec + tm2->tm_sec;
     aux->tm_min = tm1->tm_min + tm2->tm_min + (aux->tm_sec / 60) ;
     aux->tm_hour = tm1->tm_hour + tm2->tm_hour +  (aux->tm_min / 60);
     aux->tm_min %= 60;
     aux->tm_sec %= 60;
     return (aux);

 }
 bool verif_time(struct tm *tm1)
 {

     time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
     struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
     if (tm1->tm_hour == now->tm_hour && tm1->tm_min == now->tm_min)
         return true;
     else
         return false;

 }

  int main()
  {
     struct tm * after = (struct tm*)malloc(sizeof (struct tm));

     after->tm_sec = 0; // here you can modify difference between now time and time when you want to execute function 
     after->tm_min = 1;
     after->tm_hour = 0;

     after = addtime(after);
     cout << " After time" << after->tm_hour << ':' << after->tm_min<<endl;
     while (true)
     {
         if (verif_time(after))
         {
             cout << "Hello " << after->tm_hour << " : " << after->tm_min<<endl; //here you can include your function 

             after->tm_sec = 0;
             after->tm_min = 1;
             after->tm_hour = 0; // here also 

             after = addtime(after);
             cout << " After time" << after->tm_hour << ':' << after->tm_min<<endl;


         }
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To me that sounds like a candidate for the Observer Design Pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#C.2B.2B

Spawn a thread which will intermittantly check for feeds and then call the handleEvent method in your main class/concrete observor class.  That way your main class will not be in a wait state.